# Inject Angular JS in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, angularjs, shadow-dom

We have a proper Angular JS 1.4 application with App, Controller and service layers that works in VF page which we need to replicate exactly in LWC.

We have tried using **LWC:dom="manual"** to inject angular components inside LWC component, but it is not working. I can understand LWC is owning the DOM manipulation and not allowing the Angular to manipulate the DOM. I want to switch this DOM Manipulation from LWC to Angular. Can someone help here?

Comment: Are you aware that Angular JS version you are using is no longer supported? Very bad news if anything goes wrong _including_ security issues. See https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status.

Comment: Have you seen [this blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/11/how-to-use-apex-natively-with-svelte-vue-and-preact-within-lwc)? It doesn't address Angular specifically, but does show how you can load third-party frameworks in LWC in general.